# Why is style not being applied to the child elements in this example?

Tags: html, css, styles, element

ex:

I have a child element of a li:

```
<li class="element1">
    <p>Heading</p>
     ...
     ...
     ...
</li>
```

I want to apply the following style to p. I attempt to do this using the following CSS code.

```
li.p {
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```

This doesn't work, so I try another method. I add the class "heading" to the p elements. Then I write the same style I attempted to apply to li.p to the class #heading.

It still doesn't work. Why is this?

Comment: you might want to read this one. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: @user3450277, if an answer helps you, please mark it as correct so it helps others in the future who stumble upon this question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll do that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing the CSS as if `p` is a class (`li.p` would style elements that are `<li class="p">`), so remove the full-stop and it should be

```
li > p {
  // Style here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`P` is there not a class it's a tag so don't need `dot` with `p` and `p` is the child of `li` , so just put a space between `li` and `p`. Change your code like this.

```
li p {
      font-style: bold;
      text-align: left;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

use to this way

```
li p {
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```

you apply to css li.p effect only to li `class`

```
<li class="p">
```